# flutter: type '(DocumentSnapshot<MyObject>) => MyObject' is not a subtype of type '(DocumentSnapshot<Object>) => MyObject'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I have difficulties to read (and show) data from firebase DB.
I get this warning:
type '(DocumentSnapshot) => GivitUser' is not a subtype of type '(DocumentSnapshot) => GivitUser'

I realy don't know what I'm doing wrong, I tried to convert from DocumentSnapshot to DocumentSnapshot but without success.
this is my database.dart file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:givit_app/models/givit_user.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  DatabaseService({@required this.uid});

  final CollectionReference userCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

  Future<void> updateGivitUserData(
      String email, String fullName, String password, int phoneNumber) async {
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).set({
      'Email': email,
      'Full Name': fullName,
      'Password': password,
      'Phone Number': phoneNumber,
    });
  }

  Future<GivitUser> getGivitUser(String uid) async {
    return await userCollection.doc(uid).get().then((user) => user.data());
  }

  GivitUser _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<GivitUser> snapshot) {
    return GivitUser(
      uid: uid,
      email: snapshot.data().email,
      fullName: snapshot.data().fullName,
      phoneNumber: snapshot.data().phoneNumber,
    );
  }

  Stream<GivitUser> get userData {
    return userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots().map(_userDataFromSnapshot);
  }
}
```

and this is where I try to use the database.dart file and present the data:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GivitUser user = Provider.of<GivitUser>(context);
    final DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);
    return StreamBuilder<GivitUser>(
        stream: db.userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Loading();
          }
          print('after getter');
          print(snapshot.data);
          GivitUser givitUser = snapshot.data;
          return Scaffold(
          ....
          ....
          ....
```

Thank in advance, I will appreciate any help :)

edit: a screenshot of the error:
[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7zGN.png)

Comment: Hi There. Could you post your exact full error or share a screenshot of the error.

Comment: yes, I added a screenshot at the end of the post :)

Comment: Could you check if the below answer solves your problem ?

Comment: sadly, no. I explained why now

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line `userCollection.doc(uid).snapshots()` returns `Stream<DocumentSnapshot>` and not `Stream<DocumentSnapshot<GivitUser>>` as you declared in the `_userDataFromSnapshot` argument.

[Reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/snapshots.html)

> Stream<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots({bool
> includeMetadataChanges = false})

You need to change this block of code below:

```dart
    GivitUser _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot<GivitUser> snapshot) {
        //...
      }
```

to this:

```dart
    GivitUser _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
       //...
      }
```

`snapshot.data()` returns a [Map<String, dynamic>](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html) object.
So you can get your data like you would from a Map object.

The `_userDataFromSnapshot` method can be updated to:

```dart
    GivitUser _userDataFromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        var snapshotData = snapshot.data() as Map;
        return GivitUser(
           uid: uid,
           email: snapshotData['Email'],
           fullName: snapshotData['Full Name'],
           phoneNumber: snapshotData['Phone Number'],
        );
   }
```

Comment: It's does make sense but then I can't read my snapshot data, as example this line:            email: snapshot.data().email. because he doesn't know GivitUser fields. I tried to cast it but it's doesnt work either

Comment: @JohnLennon, I've updated the answer. Check it out and it should work.

Comment: still no, the error is: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: I've casted the `snapshot.data()` to a `Map` in the answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, what helped me was trying to get the collection first and then working on this specific document, maybe try to change this code:

```
final DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);
return StreamBuilder<GivitUser>(
    stream: db.userData,
```

to this code:

```
final DatabaseService db = DatabaseService(uid: user.uid);
return StreamBuilder<GivitUser>(
    stream: db.userCollection.doc(db.uid).get(),
```

like this documents says https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#one-time-read

and then you can get to the field like:

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
/...
    Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data.data();
```

I hope it will help you too! :)

Comment: saw this solution too and it didn't work in my case, but thanks :)